# track previous tab in Shiny (r)

Tags: r, shiny

In a tabset in Shiny, is there any way to track which tab panel the user has navigated *from* in order to get to the current panel? I'm nearly at the stage of using a counter variable for each panel to track how often it has been visited, but was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to use `reactiveValues` to store the current and previous tab `input` ids.  A minimal example app doing this is shown below.  The app tracks and prints out the currently selected and previously selected tabs.

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(id = 'selected_tab',
                tabPanel('1','1'),
                tabPanel('2','2'),
                tabPanel('3','3')
    ),#tabsetPanel
    "current tab:",
    verbatimTextOutput('current_tab'),
    "previous tab:",
    verbatimTextOutput('last_tab')
  )#fPage
)#shinyUi

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #init reactive value storage
  rv = reactiveValues()

  #trigger event on tab selection change
  observeEvent(input$selected_tab, {
    #store old current tab as last tab reactive value
    rv$last_tab = rv$current_tab
    #store new current tab as cur tab reactive value
    rv$current_tab = input$selected_tab
  })

  output$current_tab = renderPrint(rv$current_tab)
  output$last_tab = renderPrint(rv$last_tab)

})#shinyserver

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: Also can I just say thank you very much for pointing me towards reactiveValues()!